# Get content of current user + Of the users that are flagged or followed

Tags: views, flags

I have a site, where `users` can follow each other using `Flag`. Currently, I am able to create a `view` which shows content from all the user the currently logged in user is following. This is done adding a `relationship` to the `flag`.

What I am creating is a feed of posts, like in Facebook. So it should also show content posted by the `current user` along with `user` followed. But I am unable to do that unless the user follows himself.

[image: Current Relationship setup.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relationship's settings, uncheck the setting that restricts content to that flag.

Use the regular view filters instead and have two filters with OR between them. They would probably be author: current and author: flag.

Comment: I have been using Drupal for close to a decade and I never knew there was an OR option in Views. :D Thank you so much for the help.